# API Development - What HTTP methods will be suitable for login, log out and forgot Password?

Tags: rest, http, authentication

As per my understanding these will be

1. PUT /login (as I will be refreshing the token in the database upon successful login)
2. ?? /Log out (I don't want to do anything in the DB so perhaps client shall handle it?)
3. Put /password (It will be writing a temporary ID that will be sent to the user in the email for another API)

Comment: Authentication is kind of a separate semantic concept from "verbs operating on nouns".  You're not really *creating* or *modifying* anything.  I see no reason why one can't just use POST for these operations.  The W3C spec even leaves POST pretty open-ended when it defines one of its uses as accepting "a block of data, such as the result of submitting a form, to a data-handling process".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "session" resource for a RESTful approach of authentication:

- login can be considered as a session creation: `POST /sessions`
- logout can be considered as a session destruction: `DELETE /sessions/<id>`

As for password update, this would be an update on the "user" resource: `PUT /users/<id>`

Answer (score 0):

@Fiddler is right. Even login, logout operations can modeled with resources. However, for my own convenience I often implement `sign-in`, `sign-up`, `sign-out` operations. If verbs are introduced instead of nouns `POST` is the only method to be used.